# Calculate $\|T\|$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $k:[0,1] \times [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ continuous, and let $K:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ be defined as
>
> $$K(f)(x)=\int_{0}^{1}k(x,y)f(y)dy$$
> Show that $K$ is a continuous linear operator, and bound its norm (and check if the norm is reached).

So I'm messing up when dealing with the supremum:

I have that $$\|Kf\|_{\infty}=sup_{x \in [0,1]}|Kf(x)|=sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left|\int_{0}^{1}k(x,y)f(y)dy\right|\leq sup_{x \in [0,1]}\int_{0}^{1}|k(x,y)||f(y)|dy$$

Now I've thought about two options, since both $f, k$ are continuous functions defined on compact domains, they both attain a maximum value, so I can say

$$sup_{x \in [0,1]}\int_{0}^{1}|k(x,y)||f(y)|dy \leq sup_{x \in [0,1]}\int_{0}^{1}M_1M_2dy=M_1M_2$$

However, I don't know if this works, I'm finding the supremum, quite confusing.

Another option is saying that since $k$ is continuous, it is therefore integrable, and further more, leting $g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}k(x,y)dy$, we have that $g$ is continuous in a compact domain, and therefore attains it maximum. In this case I will have bounded $\|Kf\| \leq N_1M_2$ where $N_1=max\{g(x):x \in [0,1]\}$

I don't think that $M_1=N_1$ and I don't know if one of the two approaches is wrong. What do you say?

Comment: Both approaches look correct but the latter yields a better result. ($N_1 \leq M_1$ by the standard inequality for integrals).

Comment: There is a minor error in the second approach: Instead of defining $g$, set $N_1 = \int_0^1 \vert k(x,y) \vert dy$. If for example $k(x,y) = -1 \forall x,y$ then the inequality does not hold.

Comment: But $\int_{0}^{1}|k(x,y)|dy$ is a function, so that's why I define $g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}|k(x,y)|dy$

Comment: Yes, nevermind! You didn't put absolute values there above though!

Comment: Really, $M_1,M_2$ just pop up out of nowhere. You should define them.